# Remove value from FormControl based on value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I need to remove the element from `productForm` based on the value: "Ticket stock", but I'm able to remove items only based on invalid, pristine, dirty, etc.

```js
let desc = "Ticket stock"
// let index = this.productForm.controls.findIndex((control) => control.pristine);
const index = (this.productForm as FormArray).controls.findIndex(
  (control) => control.invalid
);
console.log(index);
this.productForm.removeAt(index);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the answer.

1. Specify the `control` as `FormGroup` type.
2. Access the `productDesc` control from `FormGroup` and get its value to compare.

```js
removeProduct() {
  let desc = 'Ticket stock';

  const index = (this.productForm as FormArray).controls.findIndex(
    (control: FormGroup) => control.controls.productDesc.value == desc
    // Or
    // (control: FormGroup) => control.controls['productDesc'].value == desc
  );
  console.log(index);

  if (index > -1)
    this.productForm.removeAt(index);
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eh6clt?file=src/app/app.component.ts)